# Delete Secure Third Party Cookie (not HttpOnly)

Tags: javascript, cookies, third-party-cookies

I trying to delete a cookie and my function is working for some cookies but not the one I want to delete.

Dummy details of the cookie:

Name: xyzabc,
Value: 1,
Path: /,
Domain: .abcd.com (third party domain),
Expiry: 2024-09-12T19:57:15.000Z,
httpOnly: No,
Secure: Yes,

Function I am using:

```
function deleteCookies(cookieNames) {
for (var i = 0; i < cookieNames.length; i++) {
document.cookie = cookieNames[i] + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;domain=.abcd.com';
}
}

var cookiesToDelete = ['xyzabc'];
deleteCookies(cookiesToDelete);
```

Is there any reason this is not working for the above cookie with a same configuration?

Hoping xyzabc would get deleted but it doesn't. I tried it with two other non secure and non httpOnly cookie and those got deleted

Comment: "Domain: .abcd.com (third party domain)" - Some clarification is needed for this part. Is `abcd.com` the domain where your function `deleteCookies` is located or called? If it's not, you can't delete those cookies.

Comment: It is the demdex cookie located in the demdex.net domain. It is owned by Adobe and is used to sync data from their data collection servers to sync ids to enable cross domain tracking. My function is located in my adobe tag manager which is my company domain.